# SSRS Report with Logo Image export to Excel

Tags: excel, reporting-services, report

I have created some reports with the Microsoft SQL Server Report Builder and I'm trying to add a logo image to the top of the report. The report works so far and I managed to add the logo.

The problem is, that the logo doesn't show up after exporting it to Excel.

What I have tried so far (Image is Embedded and not from a Database or External):

- Set a background image for the whole report and use different BackgroundRepeat settings.
  Result: Clip worked nice while displaying on the web browser, but the image was repeated x and y direction when exporting to Excel.
- I have tried to edit the RDL manually and set the BackgroundRepeat to "NoRepeat" for the background image. Result: Couldn't upload the report because of invalid BackgroundRepeat value.
- I have created an extra textbox for the image and only added a whitespace so that the field would be displayed.
  Result: Worked fine in browser, empty cell in Excel (I have read about Excel not being able to display images in cells).
- I have created a header in the Report Builder and added the logo image there. Result: Again good in Browser, empty cells when exporting to Excel.

I hope someone can help me with this problem. I just want to have the logo somewhere in the top (preferably top left above the table), only once (not repeating) and both for displaying the report in the browser and for the excel export.

EDIT: The screenshots are from the last bulletpoint version. The file format is jpeg and set in the MIMEType field.

Report-Online:

[image]
Excel-Export-Version:

[image]

Comment: Can you give a screenshot of what is being exported to Excel, where the logo should be?  What format is your image?  Is the MIME Type set appropriately to match this image format?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was able to replicate your problem. The issue is that background images (whether it's the background image of a rectangle or textbox or table cell) will not be carried into an Excel output. You need to create an image object. As far as I can tell, the image object will carry through to an Excel exported file. I tried numerous combinations of settings and the image appeared in the Excel file each time. Please note that you can even create an image object and then drag that image into the cell of a tablix and it will still appear in the Excel file. That said, when you drag an image object into a tablix cell, the cell cannot contain anything but that image.

Is there a particular reason why you're using the image as a background to a textbox rather than as an image object?

By the way, I've verified this in SSRS 2008 and SSRS 2008 R2

Comment: The only reason I didn't use the image object was that I was not aware of it. My search only found posts and questions about background images or header. I have tried your approach and it worked just the way I had in mind. Thank you sir.

Comment: I did the same thing when I started out! In fact, I went to some of my dashboards which were using rectangles with background images and they didn't export to Excel either. I think once you start using image objects, you'll see that they work far better than background images anyway, so long as you're not trying to layer content.